# How to extract key value pairs into dict if other tags are present?

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to extract Key/Value{1,2} pairs from a HTML table with python and pull them into a dictionary.

The table elements look not always the same, which is the reason for my question.

A minimal example:

```
  <div class="grabme">
  <table>
     <tbody>

        <tr>
           <td colspan="2">
              <p class="1st 2nd 3rd">
                 Box Headline</p>
           </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td><strong>First Key</strong></td>
           <td><span>Value</span></td>
           <script>
           </script>
        </tr>

        <tr>
              <td><strong>2. Key</strong></td>
              <td><a>Value</a><br></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td><strong>3. Key</strong></td>
           <td>Value</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td><strong>4. Key</strong></td>
           <td>
           <a >Val 1</a>
              Val 2

              <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                       $('.class').click(function (e) {
                          e.bla();
                          sel.bla('/bla/bla', {
                                bla: true
                             }
                          );
                       });
                    });
                 </script>
              </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
              <td><strong>5. Key</strong></td>
              <td>
                 <i></i>
                 Value
              </td>
        </tr>

     </tbody>

     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="2">
              <p class="">
                 Heading 2</p>
           </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td><strong>6. Key</strong></td>
           <td>Value</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Getting the key is easy:

```
keys = response.xpath('//div[@class="grabme"]/table/tbody/tr/td/strong/text()').extract()
```

Unfortunately I can not get all Keys in the example, as Key 6 is within a new tbody. But as a hack, I could get it seperatly and apend to dict later.

Getting the values is a lot harder. My best shot is this:

```
values = [remove_tags(w).strip() for w in response.xpath('//div[@class="grabme"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract()]
```

This unfortunatelly does not work, due to the extra html tags.
If I would be able to grab all values, then I could pull them into a dict:

```
dict = {first: second for first, second in zip(keys, values)}
```

This part might also be tricky, as the example shows that Key 4 has 2 Values. it would be OK to put them into one value with a seperator so I can later process accordingly.

How do I get the values in my example or even better, is there a smarter way in getting a dictionary of all the desired key, value pairs?

This attempt failed because of the difference in structure:

```
cells = response.xpath('//div[@class="grabme"]/tbody/tr/td/text()').extract()
dict = {first: second for first, second in zip(cells[::2], cells[1::2])}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this XPath to match both keys and values:

```
//div[@class="grabme"]//td/strong/text() | //div[@class="grabme"]//td[strong]/following-sibling::td//text()[normalize-space() and (parent::td or parent::a or parent::span)]
```

or split it into

```
//div[@class="grabme"]//td/strong/text()  # keys
//div[@class="grabme"]//td[strong]/following-sibling::td//text()[normalize-space() and (parent::td or parent::a or parent::span)]  # values
```

*Update*

```
items = {}
for row in response.xpath('//div[@class="grabme"]//tr[td[strong]]'):
    items[row.xpath('./td/strong/text()').extract_first()] = [td.strip() for td in row.xpath('./td[strong]/following-sibling::td//text()[normalize-space() and (parent::td or parent::a or parent::span)]').extract()]
```

Comment: Interesting approch, much better then what I have but still not getting the key/value pairs since they run out of sync due to the 2 values. I get '\n' values with the code before your edit, and now the javascript tags as well with the normalize-space attribute.

Comment: @merlin , can you update your HTML code sample if provided XPath doesn't work as expected as for now it work fine for me...

Comment: I added the JS code which the xpath pulls into the dictionary and adds many \ns and additional elements. I would need key 4 and its values: val1|val2

Comment: Much better, but still out of sync. The second value becomes the next key, so it is offset by 1. Also ther are \n: "\n      Val1 \n\n" elements in the values.

Comment: @merlin , check update and let me know if issue still persist. P.S. I don't use Scrapy, so I'm not sure that syntax is correct...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185681/discussion-between-merlin-and-andersson).